# Create new array of objects from two existing array of objects with differing lengths?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know similar topics are discussed here ad nauseam, but I'm having issues figuring this out for my specific case.

I have a set of data coming into a graphql resolver, where I have to make 3 inserts.

The data coming in looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Item 1',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    url: null,
    user_id: 1,
    category_name: 'Category 1',
    qty: null
  },
  ... other raw data
]
```

I'm then taking that data, and formatting it into two separate arrays of Categories and Items. Now, I'm trying to create an array of CategoryItems to be inserted into a join table.

Here are some examples as to what the arrays might look like:

*items*

```
[
  {
    id: 677,
    name: 'Item 1',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    url: null,
    user_id: 1
    created_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:22.810136+00:00',
    updated_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:22.810136+00:00',
  },
  {
    id: 678,
    name: 'Item 2',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    url: null,
    user_id: 1
    created_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:22.810136+00:00',
    updated_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:22.810136+00:00',
  },
  {
    id: 679,
    name: 'Item 3',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    url: null,
    user_id: 1
    created_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:22.810136+00:00',
    updated_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:22.810136+00:00',
  },
  ...other items
]
```

*categories*

```
[
  {
    id: 148,
    name: 'Category 1',
    list_id: 2,
    updated_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:23.09351+00:00',
    created_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:23.09351+00:00',
  },
  {
    id: 149,
    name: 'Category 2',
    list_id: 2,
    updated_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:23.09351+00:00',
    created_at: '2022-07-28T18:00:23.09351+00:00',
  },
  ... other categories
]
```

What I'm trying to do now is create an array of CategoryItems with a category_id, item_id, and position key. So the above data might be represented in a new array in this manner:

*What I Want*

```
[
  { category_id: 148, item_id: 677, position: 1 },
  { category_id: 148, item_id: 678, position: 2 },
  { category_id: 149, item_id: 679, position: 1 },
]
```

Notice that for each Category, there are multiple Items, so when looping through it needs to increment the position by 1 until it reaches the next Category.

**Edit:** Including the full resolver

```ts
import { Context } from '@/context';
import { CsvImportInput, CsvImportResponse } from '@/generated/types';
import { genericError } from '@/helpers/errors';
import { getUserId } from '@/helpers/utils';
import formatCsv from '@/helpers/formatCsv';
import { getUniqueListBy } from '@/helpers/functions';
import supabase from '@/lib/supabase';

const csvImport = async (_parent: any, { input }: { input: CsvImportInput }, context: Context): Promise<CsvImportResponse> => {
  const userId = getUserId(context.token);

  if (!userId) {
    return {
      success: false,
      ...genericError({ message: 'Must supply user id', path: 'Csv import resolver: try' }),
    };
  }

  const { data, list_id } = input;

  try {
    const formattedData = formatCsv(data, userId);

    // bulk insert items
    const { data: bulkInsertData, error: bulkInsertError } = await supabase
      .from('items')
      .insert(formattedData);
    console.log({ bulkInsertData });
    console.log({ bulkInsertError });

    if (!bulkInsertData || bulkInsertError) {
      return {
        success: false,
        ...genericError({ message: 'Error importing items', path: 'Csv import resolver: try' }),
      };
    }

    // if not attaching to specific list
    if (!list_id) {
      return {
        success: true,
        errors: null,
      };
    } else {
      // create categories
      const newCategories = data.map(item => ({ name: item.category_name, list_id }));
      const uniqueCategories = getUniqueListBy(newCategories, 'name');
      console.log('uniqueCategories: ', uniqueCategories);

      const { data: categoriesData, error: categoriesError } = await supabase
        .from('categories')
        .insert(uniqueCategories);
      console.log({ categoriesData });
      console.log({ categoriesError });

      if (!categoriesData || categoriesError) {
        return {
          success: false,
          ...genericError({ message: 'Error importing categories', path: 'Csv import resolver: try' }),
        };
      }

      // create category_items
      // const newCategoryItems = bulkInsertData.map(( item, index ) => ({
        // category_id: categoriesData.find(category => category.id === item.category.id)?.id,
        // item_id: item.id,
        // position: index,
      // }));
    }

    return {
      success: true,
      errors: null,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
    return {
      success: false,
      ...genericError({ message: 'Error importing items', path: 'Csv import resolver: catch' }),
    };
  }
};

export default csvImport;
```

Comment: What's the correlation between the two arrays? They don't immediately appear (to me) to have anything in common.

Comment: @Andy you're right, this is a simplified version of the actual larger function I'm working with. The function is receiving a set of data, in which each Item has a "category_name". I'm then formatting the data into the Item and Category objects you see above.

Comment: *"I'm then taking that data, and formatting it into two separate arrays of Categories and Items."* - by what logic? And why you do that if you want to join them?

Comment: @Andy I went ahead and added the full resolver, I hope that helps. The two arrays I'm formatting are being used to supply the Supabase insert(), but I'm needing the return values from those (`bulkInsertData` and `categoriesData`) because those contain the actual ids.

Comment: @J.Jackson So by what logic can you match an item (from the input `data`) to its `bulkInsertData` value and by what logic can you match a category (from the input `data`) to its `categoriesData` value? We don't know what `formatCsv` or `supabase.….insert(…)` does.

Comment: @Bergi That might be where I'm getting hung up actually. I updated my post with my attempt, which looks for `item.category.id`. I'm trying to find out if Supabase allows me to return foreign tables from inserts right now to allow for that. Supabase is simply a cloud Postgres client, and returns postgresql data.

Comment: In the case that `insert()` is just a regular Postgres `INSERT` statement, generating the ids for you, it's guaranteed that the data you get back is in the same order as the data that you passed in, so you can match the rows by index. It looks like for your categories, you'll want to build a lookup `Map` from name to id. For the items, I can't really tell since you haven't posted `formatCsv`

Comment: Also it might help if you could post the schemas of those tables. And can an item have multiple categories? If yes, how is that represented in your input data? If no, why do you have an extra relation table instead of storing the `category_id` right inside your `item` table?

Comment: @Bergi the formatCsv function isn't doing much other than enforcing that certain values are Boolean or deleting extra properties, and it returns a copy of that array. An item can only belong to one category, and I have a join table to add an additional property of `position` to be used for drag and drop features. I believe at one point, I had it configured so that an item could belong to more than one category, but I've since revised that approach, so you may be correct in leading me down a path of removing that join table there, and adding both `category_id` and `position` to the Items table.